# Missing image cross and border in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

In cases where the missing image (broken link to image) is placed for internet explorer it shows a cross and border.

Can we remove that cross and the border for broken images?

[Internet Explorer 7 image http://img295.imageshack.us/img295/3029/internetexplorer.png](http://img295.imageshack.us/img295/3029/internetexplorer.png)

See below for how it looks on firefox

[Firefox broken image http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/1123/firefoxg.png](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/1123/firefoxg.png)

We need to get rid of the border and cross for broken image. Can this be fixed by CSS?

Comment: Why would you load a missing image in the first place?

Comment: We have a database of lots of images. In some cases there might be a missing image BUT we do not want to show a missing images like in IE.

Also, there is an overhead to scan each folder and to check if the image is present or not before showing it to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you must use javascript. You can use something like this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onerror = function () {
        imgs[i].parentNode.removeChild(imgs[i]);
    }
}
```

with this function you will remove all images with errors.

Comment: Thanks, any CSS solution for this? We also may have some divs loaded by AJAX and we might not be able to attach this onerror to each image.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, why can't you just check if the image exists in your server-side script before outputting the HTML? There shouldn't be much of an overhead.

In PHP it would be something like:

```
<?php
if (file_exists($imgUrl)) {
    echo '<img src="', $imgUrl, '" alt="" />';
}
?>
```